# How to correctly handle an iterator for upper_bound

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a C++ map, called tableMap, with is a `std::map<int, std::string>`.

```
void processMap(int key) {
  std::map<int, std::string>::const_iterator iter;
  while (true) {
     // key is an argument to the function
     iter = tableMap.upper_bound(key);
     --iter;
     std::string value = iter->second;
     // do something else  
     ...
  }
}
```

The point is I'm not handling the `upper_bound` function call correctly. Also, I can't just check that

```
if (iter != tableMap.end())
```

because if the key is on the last element, then `upper_bound` would return `end()`. From the `C++` API, we have:

> **Return iterator to upper bound
>   Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the container whose key is considered to go after k.**

I'm clearly not handling the corner cases, and that piece of code is buggy. What should I do in other to cover the corner cases? Should I replace `upper_bound()` by `find()` or `lower_bound()` ?

The goal is to to find the next element greater than `key`, so that's why I'm decreasing `iter`. The reason was some overlapping ranges in the map.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003d3ba69eea in std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.5.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.4-4.el6.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.8.2-3.el6_0.3.x86_64 libcom_err-1.41.12-3.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 libibverbs-1.1.5mlnx1-1.32.gc42bcbf.x86_64 libselinux-2.0.94-2.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 openssl-1.0.0-4.el6_0.2.x86_64 pcre-7.8-3.1.el6.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003d3ba69eea in std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000da8a41 in std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int, std::string >::operator-- (this=0x7fffffffb8b0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:274
#2  0x0000000000de18db in processMap (
    this=0x17107b8,key=0)
```

Comment: Also, if `upper_bound()` returns `begin()`, then your following `--iter` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If the goal is to find the next element after `key`, there is no need to decrement the iterator. Should it be `end()`, this simply means there is no element greater than `key`. Just checking `if (iter != tableMap.end())` should be sufficient.

Comment: Note that for `map`, there's not much point in using `upper_bound`. The usual reason to use `upper_bound` is to find the last item with a specified key, but `map` only allows one item with any given key. `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` are primarily useful for containers that allow multiple equivalent keys (e.g., `multimap`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin that's not correct. `upper_bound` gives the first element that's *greater* than the argument. Consider a `set {2,4,8}` and `upper_bound(5)` on it, you'll get the iterator pointing to 8. `find(5)` will return `end()`. (same holds for maps, of course). Only the combination of both `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` corrensponds to `find` in unique key containers.

Answer (score 3):

Compare these two:

> The goal is to to find **the next element greater than key**, so that's why I'm decreasing iter. The reason was some overlapping ranges in the map.
>
> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the container **whose key is considered to go after k**

That means, `upper_bound` already does what you need. So don't decrement the iterator. There are three corner cases:

1. The map is empty, then there is only one iterator, namely `end()`/`begin()`. Decrement, increment and dereferencing of iter wil give UB.
2. The map contains no value with a key greater than your argument. `upper_bound` will return `end()`, so don't dereference it.
3. The map contains only values with keys greater than your argument. `upper_bound` will return `begin()`. Your decrement is UB then, but since it's wrong anyways, you can just use it and dereference it.

So you only have to handle the first two cases, where `upper_bound` returns `end()`:

```
void processMap(int key) {
  while (true) {
     auto iter = tableMap.upper_bound(key);
     if (iter == tableMap.end())
       break; //there is no entry with a greater key

     // use iter...
  }
}
```